# Default values of parametrs for own functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, defaults

I am writing my own jQuery functions. Is it possible to set the default values of the function parameters?

Answer (score 9):

One way to do this is to check the parameters. For example:

```
function test(paramA) {
    if (paramA == null) {
        paramA = defaultValue;
    }
    // use paramA here
}
```

Another possibility is this:

```
function test() {
    var paramA = defaultValue;
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        paramA = arguments[0];
    }
    // use paramA here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i can't vote right now but agree with color2life.

```
a = a || "something"
```

is probably the most concise and readable version.

Comment: Don't forget the semicolon at the end of the line. Even though JS will put those in for you where it can, it's good practice to do it yourself.

Comment: This will fail with booleans. If you pass in false, and your default value is true, it will always be set to true.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check for `undefined` instead of `null`.

```
var f=function(param){
  if(param===undefined){
    // set default value for param
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if not defined then a have "something"**

```
a = a || "something"; // setting default value
```

Comment: This will fail with booleans. If you pass in false, and your default value is true, it will always be set to true.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.yourFunction= function(opts) {
        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn.yourFunction.defaults, opts);

        ....

        $.fn.yourFunction.defaults = {
        param1: "someval",
        param2: "",
        param3: "#ffffff"
    };

})(jQuery);
```